# How to add Pattern Fill with thicker lines

Tags: highcharts

Trying to add a fill with diagonal lines like this, strokeWidth does not seem to be helping with this
[Needed pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArqzF.png)

Currently have d: 'M 0 6 L 6 0 M -1 1 L 1 -1 M 5 7 L 7 5', which is giving the correct orientation/direction of the lines but does not have the correct thickness

Comment: I noticed that you have already created a similar topic on our forum, so the thread will be continued there: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=51272